# International train left Italy with 90 minutes delay and arrived 110 minutes late. Can I be compensated and where to claim?

Tags: trains, compensation, delays

Recently, I took an Eurocity train from Italy to Switzerland. I purchased my ticket from a Trenitalia self-service kiosk at Milano Centrale. The train left with a delay of 90 minutes. My destination station was reached with an announced delay of 110 minutes.

I purchase the ticket roughly 3 hours before posted departure time. There was no known delay at that moment.

Am I eligible for a compensation? Which rules do apply? In this case of international connection, which railway company should be contacted about it, Trenitalia or SBB?

Comment: I would have thought your claim is against the vendor, Trenitalia. However, their web-site is rather coy about how much they might pay you.

Comment: Was the delay already known when you purchased the ticket? If not, I believe you are entitled to a compensation of 25% of the price of the ticket. The fact that it crosses into Switzerland may be an issue, but as far as I understand it, Italy have not exempted such trips from the scope of the rail passenger rights regulations.

Comment: There was no posted delay when I purchased the ticket, and it was before departure time.